# Найти сумму и произведение цифр числа

Tags: python

```
num = int(input())
numb=num//100
numc=num-numb*121
numd=num-numb*120
print('Сумма цифр =', numb+numc+numd)
print('Произведение цифр =', numb*numc*numd)


Num=123
```

Comment: Здесь все не так. объясните логику вашего кода.

Comment: @Егор это вы описали задачу, а не логику. Логика объясняет почему вы делаете то, что написано в коде. Откуда у вас в коде 100, 121 и 120? Почему вы отнимаете одно от другого? Вот это логика.

Comment: Я понял но я торопился по этому и не стал сильно податься к подробностям) проголосовать негативно насколько я понимаю снижает видимость вопроса в портале. Если не понравился вопрос не обязательно спалить можете мимо пройти.

Comment: Что вам нужно всем понятно. И я вам уже написал, что у вас все неправильно. Просто интересно, каким образом вы пришли к такому коду, который никак не связан с данной задачей.

Comment: Именно так меня учат, насколько я понимаю что по сложному пути но я по другому не могу. Почему отнимаю ну потому что мне надо как то выводить цифру 2 и 3 и сложить и умножить всех трех цифр(1,2,3) разделить 123 по цифрам по другому пока не умею

Comment: Так почему 120? Что вы будет делать, если вместо 123 окажется число 765? Писать новую программу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def digitize(n):
    return list(map(int, str(n)))
    
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum(digitize(n))

def prod_digits(n):
    res = 1
    for d in digitize(n):
        res *= d
    return res

num = int(input())   # 234
print(f'Сумма цифр = {sum_digits(num)}')
print(f'Произведение цифр = {prod_digits(num)}')
```

---

вывод:

```
Сумма цифр = 9
Произведение цифр = 24
```

Comment: Но так пока не проходили не понимаю тут что происходит почти 70%. У меня оч примитивный способ решение пока(((

Comment: @Егор, мы же не знаем, что вы уже знаете и понимаете, а что нет. :) Я привел пример простого, но идиоматического решения, которое не использует модулей... PS правильных решений у данной задачи может быть достаточно много ;)

Comment: Спасибо Макс что мимо не проходите, я прекрасно все понимаю((( но меня тоже за это дрючать по примитивнымы способами-_-